# What is hook_menu_alter used for?

Tags: hooks

In simple terms, what is hook_menu_alter for? I understand callbacks in general, but I'm not quite sure if this method is misnamed in a sense, as I see it used in the context of permissions rather than menus. I'm probably just confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your confusion comes from the fact that Drupal 6 and 7 mixes menu and routing. One set of hooks for both purposes, and here you have problems. If this hook was named `hook_route_alter()`, using it to alter permissions to some routes would be obvious, right? So that's what modules do, using the name they got. Personally I agree it's not most lucky naming, but once you remember that in this context, basically, **menu == routing**, it all becomes much more intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

**Change theme of particular page/menu:**

There we have used `hook_custom_theme()` hook to change theme on particular page. Instead of this we can also use `hook_menu_alter()` as another way to achieve same feature.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function custom_module_menu_alter(&$items){
  // Change 'node/add/page' page to admin theme (Assume by default node/add page uses default theme)
  $items ['node/add/page']['theme callback'] = variable_get('admin_theme');
}
```

**Change title of page/menu:**

Menu provides page titles. If we are in ‘node/add/page’ then we see page title as ‘Create Basic page’ but what if we need custom title like ‘Add page’. We can achive this using below custom module.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function custom_module_menu_alter(&$items){
  // Change 'node/add/page' title to 'Add page'
  $items ['node/add/page']['title'] = 'Add Page';
}
```

**Customize accessing a page/menu:**

For many pages/menus we restrict access to different users or on conditions. Let’s say we want restrict ‘user/register’ page in particular times.. I mean no registration will be done in 12AM - 06AM.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function custom_module_menu_alter(&$items){
  // Restrict 'user/register' page in 12AM-05AM
  $items ['user/register']['access callback'] = '_MY_MODULE_time_access';
}

    /*
     * Access callback function to restrict user registration in particular timings
     */
    function custom_module_time_access(){
      // Get current time hour like 0,1,2,3....23
      $current_time_hour = date('G');
      
      // if current time is between 0 & 5 then return false
      if($current_time_hour >= 0 && $current_time_hour <= 5 ){
        return false;
      }
      return TRUE;
    }
```

**Create duplicate page/menu:**

We can also use hook_menu_alter() hook if we want to create a duplicate page, a page with same functionality but with different url. Let’s say we want a url ‘add/page’ which acts same as of ‘node/add/page’.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function custom_module_menu_alter(&$items){
  // Copy ‘node/add/page’ page to ‘add/page’
  $items ['add/page'] = $items ['node/add/page'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With hook_menu_alter  you can manipulate $items: Associative array of menu router definitions returned from hook_menu(), you can add or remove items or manipulate menu item properties : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7